# Way to style nav bar similar to one attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in the process of trying to style this navigation bar to this image:

[image]

Currently I have this:

https://jsfiddle.net/jd3tgzme/1/

```html
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<style>
  .alphabetNav li {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #cecece;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
  }
  .noNav li {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
  }
  .letter:hover {
    color: red;
  }
  .letter:visited {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .submenuDiv ul {
    display: inline;
  }
  .submenuDiv ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #cecece;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .submenuDiv {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".letter").click(function(e) {
      var letter = $(this).html().trim();
      $(".submenuDiv").hide();
      x = e.clientX - 100;
      pos = $(this).position();
      y = pos.top + 50;
      $("#div" + letter).css({
        left: x,
        top: y,
        position: 'absolute'
      });
      $("#div" + letter).show();

    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class='alphabetNav'>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterA'>A</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterB'>B</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterC'>C</a>
    </li>
    <ul class='noNav'>
      <li>D</li>
    </ul>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterE'>E</a>
    </li>
    <ul class='noNav'>
      <li>F</li>
    </ul>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterG'>G</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterH'>H</a>
    </li>
    <ul class='noNav'>
      <li>I</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='noNav'>
      <li>J</li>
    </ul>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterK'>K</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterL'>L</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterM'>M</a>
    </li>
    <ul class='noNav'>
      <li>N</li>
    </ul>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterO'>O</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterP'>P</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterQ'>Q</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterR'>R</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterS'>S</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterT'>T</a>
    </li>
    <ul class='noNav'>
      <li>U</li>
    </ul>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterV'>V</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterW'>W</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterX'>X</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterY'>Y</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class='letter' id='letterY'>Z</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Submenu for letter A -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divA'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Abbotsford-Mission (B.C.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter B -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divB'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Barrie (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Brantford (Ont.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter C -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divC'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Calgary (Alta.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter D -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divD'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Apple
      </li>
      <li>
        Artist
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter E -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divE'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Edmonton (Alta.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter F -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divF'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Apple
      </li>
      <li>
        Artist
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter G -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divG'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Greater Sudbury (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Guelph (Ont.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter H -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divH'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Halifax (N.S.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Hamilton (Ont.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter I -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divI'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Apple
      </li>
      <li>
        Artist
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter J -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divJ'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Apple
      </li>
      <li>
        Artist
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter K -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divK'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Kelowna (B.C.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Kingston (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Kitchener-Cambridge-Waterloo (Ont.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter L -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divL'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        London (Ont.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter M -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divM'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Moncton (N.B.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Montréal (Que.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter N -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divN'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Apple
      </li>
      <li>
        Artist
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter O -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divO'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Oshawa (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Ottawa-Gatineau (Ont.-Que.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter P -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divP'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Peterborough (Ont.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter Q -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divQ'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Québec (Que.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter R -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divR'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Regina (Sask.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter S -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divS'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Saguenay (Que.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Saint John (N.B.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Saskatoon (Sask.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Sherbrooke (Que.)
      </li>
      <li>
        St. Catharines-Niagara (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        St. John's (N.L.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter T -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divT'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Thunder Bay (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Toronto (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Trois-Rivières (Que.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter U -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divU'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Apple
      </li>
      <li>
        Artist
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter V -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divV'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Vancouver (B.C.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Victoria (B.C.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Submenu for letter W -->
  <div class='submenuDiv' id='divW'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Windsor (Ont.)
      </li>
      <li>
        Winnipeg (Man.)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

I was just wondering how I can style it so that 'D, F, I, J, N, U, X, Y, & Z' can be greyed out and unclickable.  I was also just wondering how to get the grey background and when a letter it clicked, the background fills with white (like the M in the image). Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- To make unclickable letters greyed out, you can use this CSS:

```
.noNav li {
    cursor:default;
    color:#ccc
}
```

2- To add a gray background to your navigation, you will need to set a height for your `alphabetNav` and a background like this:

```
.alphabetNav {
    width:550px;
    height:27px
}
```

3- To modify the style of the clicked element, you will need to add something like this in your click function:

```
$(".letter").parent().removeClass('current');
$(this).parent().addClass('current');
```

4- To style the clicked element, you will need to add something like this in your css:

```
li.current {
    background:#fff
}
```

5- To add rounded corner, you will need to use `border-radius`in your css like this:

```
.alphabetNav li {
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
```

You can see your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jd3tgzme/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciate it.  May I ask another question, how do you round the boxes the letters are in?

Comment: You are the absolute best! Thank you so very much for your help. It was probably such an easy solution for you, but it taught me tons! (New to html/css/javascript here)!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS

```
.noNav{
    color:#aaa;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jd3tgzme/2/

---

For the active LI: https://jsfiddle.net/jd3tgzme/3/
 add in CSS:

```
.alphabetNav li.active{
    background-color:#fafafa;
}
```

and in jQuery:

```
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".letter").closest("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/jd3tgzme/9/

```
.noNav {
   background-color: #aaa;
}
.active {
   background-color: white!important;
}
$("#letter"+letter).parent().addClass('clicked')
```

Here I do the following:

- I changed the colour of .noNav class to grey
- I added a class called .active that turns the parent element background (Li) white, you can change the colour to match your selected background (in this case white) of the content wrapper below the navbar, and voila it blends in.
- I added border radius to the top corners of the li's of .alphabetNav to round the edges

Whats up to you:

- Remove .active from previously clicked letter when a new one is clicked. Should be simple.

P.S: The "!important" after 'white' basically means that the browser should ignore any other setting that applies to the same object. (overriding)

Cheers!